# Scala pattern matching - Identify between connection(infra) exception and data(Query) exception in Java.Sql

Tags: sql, scala, exception, pattern-matching, retry-logic

I am trying to find ways to write a code for retry only for connection exception. But every exception from Sql server is under SQLSERVEREXCEPTION.

Is there any way to differentiate connection exception from others.

```
//code idea
val result = RetryFuture(insertQuery(student:Student).recover{
 case SQLSERVEREXCEPTION: throw ex
 case _=>""
})
```

Comment: how do you connect with the database?

Comment: Connection pool-HikariCP

Comment: So you should check an error code in the exception and base on it execute retry. e.g. doobie handles it for you, so you can handily match on exception type